TYPO3 to Wordpress Migration (Users)
I got a problem with migration from TYPO3 to Wordpress.
We got like 4.000 Users in Typo3 and want to migrate them to Wordpress.
Typo3 uses BCRYPT Password Hash, and Wordpress PHPASS.
I’ve changed the Hash-Alg. to BCRYPT, and it’s working for new User, or User who already had PHPASS.
I just importet one user via. csv. and couldn’t login. Becouse of… I dont know.
Anyone of you could help me?
Plug-In I used is “GitHub - szepeviktor/password-bcrypt: Implement secure bcrypt hashed passwords in WordPress”
Love and Peace

Anything you do will always work for newer users going forward but that's ignoring compatibility with other CMS' or even existing WP users. A WP password hash isn't just a straight forward hash, it has various "salts" added that were defined in the wp-config.php and rehashes. Rather than attempt to make all the passwords keep working it would be better to reset them all. In the grand scheme of things though limiting brute force login attempts. Trying to preserve the password hashes may not be wise.

Thank you, Sir. Thats a good point.
Works for me <3
